# Table is not centered on IE, but is centered on other browsers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table that is offset to the right on Internet Explorer, but is centered on other browsers (Edge, Firefox, mobile). I'm using bootstrap, but I'm having issues finding what breaks the alignment in IE.

```html
<div class="container body-content body-padding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <p class="breadcrumbs">
                    <a href="index.html" class="">Home</a> /
                    <a href="#" class="">Services</a> /
                    <a href="#" class="">Rates</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-spacing-reduced">
            <div class="col">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h1 class="spage-header mt-5">Rates</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col rates-col">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-info">
                        <th scope="col">Service</th>
                        <th scope="col">Charge</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lots of rows</td>
                            <td>Condensed version</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col rates-col">
                <p class="spage-text no-padding">....</p>
                <p class="spage-text mb-5">....</p>
                <h3 class="spage-subheader no-padding">Our Guarantee</h3>
                <p class="spage-text no-padding">...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is not working for you, as I opened your code in IE and it is centered for me. And centered in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Edge as well.

See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gh0f.png)

My only recommendation is to double check you are using the latest Bootstrap CSS link inside your `<head>` tag. At the time of this post, this is the current version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Try that and see if that works.

I also tested with and without their JS, Popper.js, and jQuery scripts, and they had no impact. So I am guessing it's something to do with your styles.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem before, IF you are using the `<head>` with a responsive `<meta>` attribute make sure that the responsive attribute is on the first line of the `<head>` property.

Internet Explorer is pretty outdated and not really being used anymore, this could be a code support problem with IE since it's not being supported anymore for quite a few years now.

You could also try to reset your browsing data on IE for the best results of your code.
Personally if it works with all the bigger search software's (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) and also mobile I wouldn't worry about IE at all.

Hope the first paragraph helped you out :)